# MySQL joining tables on fields with different type

Tags: mysql, join

Suppose I have 2 InnoDB tables A and B.

```
Table A has a column named Acountry of type INT
Table B has a column named Bcountry of type VARCHAR

Some records in table A have in column Acountry values "356"
Some records in table B have in column Bcountry values "356,Italy"
```

How is it possible that the following join works perfectly:
(I mean I get rows where Acountry or Bcountry starts with 356)

```
SELECT A.Field1 , A.Field2 , B.Field3 , B.Field4 
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.Acountry=B.Bcountry
```

despite the fact that the 2 columns have different values
and are of different type

Any hints ? 
Is there any setting for "loose" joining ?

P.S.
I found this link http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3777
where it states that:
"This is expected behavior.
The arguments (string and number) are compared as floating-point numbers"
???

Comment: Since the columns on the `JOIN` condition have different types, MySQL converts one (or both) of them to a different type to get a common denominator. During this conversion(s) the original semantic of the values is lost and they compare using the rules of their new types (f.e., 2 < 12 but '2' > '12').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings in MySQL which *begin* with numbers will be cast as numbers up to the first non-numeric character.  So the cast operation results in only the integer at the front:

```
> SELECT CAST('356,Italy' AS INT);
+--------------------------+
| CAST('356,Italy' AS INT) |
+--------------------------+
|                      356 |
+--------------------------+
```

(Note: casting as `DECIMAL` will produce the same result)

But a similar string which has a *non-numeric* character first will cast to `0`:

```
> SELECT CAST('xx356,Italy' AS INT);
+--------------------------------+
| CAST('xx356,Italy' AS INT)     |
+--------------------------------+
|                              0 |
+--------------------------------+
```

I would consider this to be an unreliable behavior to perform a join on, even if it is unlikely to be changed in future MySQL versions. It would be much better to produce a consistent or more directly comparable value between those common columns.

#### Fix the data if possible:

First and foremost, if you are in any position to change this table structure such that `B` has consistent data, that is the *real* solution. And doing that would also allow you to make the data types of `A.ACountry` and `B.BCountry` identical (both as `INT` types) which further allows you to define a proper `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

#### Join with what you have using string operations:

But a `JOIN`'s `ON` condition can be any arbitrary expression, and MySQL offers a [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to return a substring before a delimiter. You should be able to join successfully using that:

```
SELECT
  A.*,
  B.Field3,
  B.Field4
FROM
  A
  -- Join on the first group of characters before `,` in BCountry
  INNER JOIN B ON A.ACountry = SUBSTRING_INDEX(BCountry, ',', 1)
```

This works because:

```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('356,Italy', ',', 1);
+--------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('356,Italy', ',', 1) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 356                                  |
+--------------------------------------+
```

And without the trailing string the same result:

```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('356', ',', 1);
+--------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('356', ',', 1) |
+--------------------------------+
| 356                            |
+--------------------------------+
```

Note: The string operation is likely to degrade performance of this join. Fixing the source data is again the better solution.

Comment: As it's said in the answer, the *correct* solution is to fix the design and store a single value in a column of the correct type. Storing multiple values separated no matter with what character is a bad idea. The query provided by the answer works but it is very slow because it **cannot** use any index (due to the bad design).

Comment: It's not true that an index can't be used. Simply use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` to force the join in the correct direction so an index can be used on Acountry.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you guys.
I'm currently working at a new company and found this strange query in some php code.Still figuring out various matters so I don't have a whole view of the database design and schema.